# Java best style for return statement - inside or outside if condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-style, refactoring, return

Is there a better way to write the code below? I'm checking if an object is null, returning false if it is, otherwise I check another variable and choose what to do based on that.

```
private boolean myFunction(MyObjectType myObject) {
  if (myObject == null) {
    return false;
  } else if (myInstanceVariable.myMethod()) {
    // Do something then return
    System.out.println(myObject.getSomeValue());
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is it better to have the final else statement or move the `return false` (and any other code that I may have put before it inside the final `else { }` block) outside the if statement? I could see it being safer (and fewer lines of code) to move it outside so the function is 100% guaranteed to return. Could it depend on how the compiler behaves?

```
private boolean myFunction(MyObjectType myObject) {
  if (myObject == null) {
    ...
  } else if (myVariable.myMethod()) {
    ...
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better place to ask such questions

Comment: Note that a decent IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans will not allow you to write code which does not guarantee to return the required type. And they're smart enough to work out whether your if/else chain will always return a result or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have the last return statement in the end outside any if statements.
Also last I remember, if all your returns are inside if statements you will get a compilation error stating the method doesn't have a return or that the return may not always be reached.

Comment: Can you also explain why it is better?

Comment: "if all your returns are inside if statements you will get a compilation error" is not actually a true statement. You'll only see an error if the code won't reach those return statements. Also, the reason why a single return statement is "better" is that a method with a single exit point is inherently more clear to readers than a method with multiple exit points. In practice, however, a short method with more than one exit point is plenty easy to comprehend.

Comment: @Jesper I think it depends on the situation. For instance, i would never have several exit points in a method containing only if statements or such, I'd have it return a variable, who's value is determined by the outcome of the if statements as they are checked one by one. However, if the method contains a loop, and I would like it to return when I no longer need to loop, I would set an inside exit point (a return) inside its own if statement to exit the loop and method simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is better:

```
private boolean myFunction(MyObjectType myObject) {
  if (myObject == null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (myInstanceVariable.myMethod()) {
    // Do something then return
    System.out.println(myObject.getSomeValue());
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you are returning from inside an `if` block, then you don't need an `else` block.  I find it better because the true complexity of the logic is better expressed by this less-complex looking method.  Fewer braces and less indentation makes it easier to understand, at least for me.